# Slow Loading Of Images In Android Studio App

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hi well I am a beginner and I am learning to built app recently I am working on small app name"roll dice" but whenever I increase the loop size such as about 100 it takes about 12 seconds to change the images and I want that the images change instantly such as like an animation as I click the button 
I have also check logcat and it says "increase code cache capacity to 128kb"(it is not an error message) I have also attached the logcat screenshot

```
 fun rollDice(v: View?)
{
    st=0
    rollresult?.setText("clicked")


       // var no = random!!.nextInt(6) + 1
    while(st<100) {
        dic1 = random!!.nextInt(6) + 1
        dic2 = random!!.nextInt(6) + 1
        dic3 = random!!.nextInt(6) + 1
        dice[0] = (dic1)
        dice[1] = (dic2)
        dice[2] = (dic3)


        // Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"no is "+no,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var diceset = 0
        while (diceset < 3) {

            try {// var string: String = "dice" + dice!![diceset] + ".png"
                var string = "dice" + dice[diceset] + ".png"
                var stream: InputStream = getAssets().open(string)
                var draw: Drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null)
                var test: ImageView? = diceimageview[diceset]
                test?.setImageDrawable(draw)

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.message

            }
            diceset++


        }
        st++
    }



}
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/bumptech/glide for showing images instead of creating huge bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Frame Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Frame) instead of trying to load the images one-by-one.

To do this you'll need to move your images to the `drawable` resource directory, instead of the `assets` directory. Then create an `animation-list` drawable resource from them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dice1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dice2" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dice3" android:duration="100" />

</animation-list>
```

Then load the animation into your `ImageView`.

```
diceImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice_animation)
```

And finally start the animation.

```
val diceAnimation = diceImageView.getBackground() as AnimationDrawable
diceAnimation.start()
```

Comment: Thank You @Bryan it really helped I just want to know what can I do so that the animation keeps on repeating.

Comment: @GUILRAIZ Change the [`oneshot`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#attr_android:oneshot) attribute to `false` (or just remove it, the default is `false`).